# How to get moodle quiz report

Tags: moodle

How admin could get question and answer as a report in Moodle. This is for giving to students when quiz gets over. Either I need to get questions and the answer of questions, choices and answers

Answer (score 2):

Go to the quiz.

In your administration block, under **quiz administration**, collapse the "Results" menu.

Click on "Responses".

*(Just to recap, that's Admin Block -> Quiz Administration -> Results -> Responses)*

This page will show you the list of learners + Quiz responses.

You can export this to whatever format you want. CSV works best.

Also on this same page, you can click on "Review attempt" under each student's name to view their exact responses to each question including the feedback they received. I think this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you need to export the student record by exporting all their successful attempts of quizzes in the form of PDFs (just like it displays in the "Review attempt" screen of moodle) then this needs custom development. I have found a plugin already developed for it here:
http://shispare.com/portfolio-view/moodle-export-student-work-record-to-pdfs/